# Mathematics behind the creation of 3d face mask at runtime

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I'm new in Image processing and Machine learning area. I want to create 3d mask of face at runtime.

```
import numpy as np
import dlib

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = detector(gray)
    for face in faces:
        x1 = face.left()
        y1 = face.top()
        x2 = face.right()
        y2 = face.bottom()

        landmarks = predictor(gray, face)

        for n in range(0, 68):
            x = landmarks.part(n).x
            y = landmarks.part(n).y
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)


    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

I find mention code online, which find 68 point on face.
I want to know the Mathematics behind it. All I know that partial differentiation is used but I can't understand how. Also Some details about how to create 3d face mask at runtime will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the naive answer, but why not consider reading the documentation of the library you have used?

http://dlib.net/

http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.get_frontal_face_detector

http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.shape_predictor

Quick googling also reveals numerous posts on how this library works and how it can be used

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/12/16/training-a-custom-dlib-shape-predictor/

DLIB appears to be a machine learning / deep learning library, which means they would train a predictor like a deep neuronal network on some training data, and then use that network to place points on your images. The mathematics behind that is no different than any other neuronal network. Just find some course on machine learning / deep learning, and you will learn what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In the case above the mathematics are pretty simple:

1. Use cascaded Haar filters to extract features from the image.
   You may have a look at [Haar Cascade Classifiers in OpenCV Explained Visually](https://medium.com/swlh/haar-cascade-classifiers-in-opencv-explained-visually-f608086fc42c).
2. Use [Ada Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) to generate an Ensemble of classifiers to detect a face.

For overview of this approach (First done by the Viola Jones Detector) you may have a look at [Haar Cascades, Explained](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/haar-cascades-explained-38210e57970d).